# Creating a dynamic tree in symfony 2

Tags: php, css, symfony

I am beginner in symfony 2. I have a project and I want to create a dynamic tree using css, this tree will display my categories levels.

I already tried to do it by myself, I was able to display the first 3 levels of my categories using 3 loops, but other levels are not displaying.

What I want is to know if I can use recursion or an other way to display all categories as a tree.

this the action method i used :

```
    public function afficherArborescenceAction(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $categories = $em->getRepository('PortfolioBundle:Categorie')->findByCategorieParent();
    $sousCategories = $em->getRepository('PortfolioBundle:Categorie')->findSousCategories();
    return $this->render('AdministrateurBundle:NouvelleCategorie:showCategories.html.twig',array('categories'=>$categories,'sousCategories'=>$sousCategories));
}
```

This my html code :

```
    <div style="border:1px #999999 solid;border-radius: 5px;width:350px;margin: 100px auto;padding:10px;">
<p>Les catégories:</p>
{% for categorie in categories %}
    <ul class="tree">
        <li><a href="{{path('sous_categorie',{'id': categorie.id})}}">{{ categorie.libelle }}</a>
            {% for sousCategorie in sousCategories %}

                <ul>
                    {% if sousCategorie.categorieParent == categorie.id %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{path('sous_categorie',{'id': sousCategorie.id})}}">{{ sousCategorie.libelle }}</a>
                            {% for sous in sousCategories %}       
                                {% if sous.categorieParent == sousCategorie.id %}
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{path('sous_categorie',{'id': sous.id})}}">{{ sous.libelle }}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>

            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the current tree i get, using the code above :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using [StofDoctrineExtensionBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) it is very simple to do what you want. For example this would generate nested `<ul>` of your category tree:

```
$htmlTree = $repository->childrenHierarchy(
    null,
    false,
    [
        'decorate' => true,
        'nodeDecorator' => function ($node)
        {
            return "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/search?q=$node[name]\">$node[name]</a>";
        },
        //'rootOpen' => '<ul>', leave it as is
        //'rootClose' => '</ul>',
        'childOpen' => function ($node)
        {
            return "<li data-node-id=\"$node[id]\">";
        },
        'childClose' => '</li>',
    ],
    true
);

$io->writeln($htmlTree);
```

Here is fully working example, complete process is covered, from configuring to the more advanced queries: [Hierarchical Data in Relational Databases with Symfony 4 and Doctrine](http://drib.tech/programming/hierarchical-data-relational-databases-symfony-4-doctrine).

Answer (score 0):

Check there, with the component Tree:

https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

It can do what you need exactly